# How to sort an Array[Array[Int]] supposing inner array have the same size but we don't know it

Tags: scala, sorting

Let's consider the following Array[Array[Int]

```
val array = Array(Array(7,3,2,1), Array(3,2,5,1), Array(2,1,4,6), Array(1,2,3,4))
```

I would like to have this result

```
val sortedArray = Array(Array(1,2,3,4), Array(1,2,3,5), Array(1,2,3,7), Array(1,2,4,6))
```

If we know that each inner array have the same size n we start to sort each inner array then use sortBy

```
val sortedArray = array.map(_.sorted).sortBy(x => (x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3)))
```

Unfortunately if we don't know the inner array size in advance or if it's huge we cannot proceed as seen above.
Maybe it is possible to define a custom ordering in a dynamic way..

In this case i can also do

```
val sortedArray = array.map(_.sorted).map(a => (a.reduce(_+_), a)).sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
```

But it works because elements in each array are present a uniq time for each array.

Comment: Doesn't doing only `array.map(_.sorted)` get you the results you want ?

Comment: No because i want to sort the result of `array.map(_sorted)` to have them ordered

Comment: @KyBe In your desired `sortedArray` result, shouldn't `Array(1,2,3,7)` come before `Array(1,2,4,6)`?

Comment: Little mistake of mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own `Ordering` for the array elements like:

```
val array = Array(Array(7,3,2,1), Array(3,2,5,1), Array(2,1,4,6), Array(1,2,3,4))

implicit object IntArrayOrdering extends Ordering[Array[Int]] {
  override def compare(x: Array[Int], y: Array[Int]): Int =
    compareStream(x.toStream, y.toStream)

  private def compareStream(x: Stream[Int], y: Stream[Int]): Int = {
    (x.headOption, y.headOption) match {
      case (Some(xh), Some(yh))  => 
        if (xh == yh) {
          compareStream(x.tail, y.tail)
        } else {
          xh.compare(yh)
        }
      case (Some(_), None) => 1
      case (None, Some(_)) => -1
      case (None, None) => 0
    }
  }
}

array.map(_.sorted).sorted
```

Comment: But note that this particular implementation is going to perform badly, as `tail` on arrays has to create a new array and copy elements there, unlike `List`s.

Comment: True.  A simple way to improve performance, as I did in the updated answer  above, is to turn `Array[Int]` into `Stream[Int]` before the recursion.  Of course, you might squeeze even more speed by going lower level and access the `Array[Int]` directly by index.